# What is the efficient method of utilising length() function and boolean?

Tags: java, methods

So far learned about the concepts to do a sample project on my own. But I need to know what is the efficient method in utilising the length() function and boolean. Here are the codes for two possible cases.

Case 1 :

```
String userName_Pattern = "[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*";
do {
    System.out.println("PREFERRED USERNAME (Only 6 - 14 characters)");
    new_UserName = br.readLine();
    if(new_UserName.matches(userName_Pattern)!=true) {
        System.out.println("Username must contain only letters and numbers");
    }
    if(new_UserName.length()==0) {
        System.out.println("Username cannot be blank");
    }
}while((new_UserName.matches(userName_Pattern)!=true)||(!((new_UserName.length()>5)&&(new_UserName.length()<15))));
```

Case 2 :

```
String userName_Pattern = "[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*";
boolean b;
int userName_Length;
do {
    System.out.println("PREFERRED USERNAME (Only 6 - 14 characters)");
    new_UserName = br.readLine();
    b=new_UserName.matches(userName_Pattern);
    userName_Length=new_UserName.length();
    if(b!=true) {
        System.out.println("Username must contain only letters and numbers");
    }
    if(userName_Length==0) {
        System.out.println("Username cannot be blank");
    }
}while((b!=true)||(!((userName_Length>5)&&(userName_Length<15))));
```

Logic and result for both the cases are same, but which is efficient?

1) utilising the length() and boolean directly in the condition?

or

2) Introducing new variables and checking the condition using the data in that variable?

Comment: java compiler will optimize this and both sources will provide the same performance and even byte code (at least very similar)

Comment: The second one *might* be more efficient because you are not calling *matches()* all the time. Although, I am afraid the compiler is smart enough to optimize this code and call matches only once and keep its value cached.

Comment: @Lashane The Java compiler will do no such thing.

Comment: @EJP The JIT compiler will do such [thing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm#i1077985)

Comment: @Lashane Possibly, even probably, although it's very difficult to tell, but your comment specifically mentioned the *Java* compiler and the generated byte-code, both of which statement remain incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both cases aren't perfect.

```
String userName_Pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,14}";
```

I am assuming that you don't need all letters to precede all digits?!

```
do {
    System.out.println("PREFERRED USERNAME (Only 6 - 14 characters)");
    new_UserName = br.readLine();
    userName_Length=new_UserName.length();
    correct = true;
    if( userName_Length < 6 || userName_Length > 14 ){
        System.out.println("Username must contain 6 - 14 ...");
        correct = false;
    } else
    if(! new_UserName.matches(userName_Pattern) ) {
        System.out.println("Username must contain only letters and numbers");
        correct = false;
    }

} while( ! correct );
```

Actually, you could drop the length check as the modified pattern would catch legth errors, too.

```
do {
  System.out.println("PREFERRED USERNAME (Only 6 - 14 letters and digits)");
  new_UserName = br.readLine();
  correct = true;
  if(! new_UserName.matches(userName_Pattern) ) {
    System.out.println("Username must contain only letters and numbers, min 8,  max 14");
    correct = false;
  }
} while( ! correct );
```

Comment: lol.. I just realised the poor quality of my code.. Because this is my very first coding on a project.. Thank you all..  I learned more about the boolean and especially the pattern (Regex.pattern) about it checks the length too..

Answer (score 1):

*Neither* of them is particularly efficient: both can be improved significantly. You don't need to call matches() twice in the loop; you don't need to explicitly compare booleans to 'true'; you don't need to test the length if it has already failed the matches() test; etc etc etc.

On the other hand none of it needs any optimization at all, as the user input is the rate-determining step. However I would clean it up anyway, as it is just poor quality code. By making better use of the regular expression you can simplify the whole thing to this:

```
    final String userName_Pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,14}";
    for (;;)
    {
        System.out.println("PREFERRED USERNAME (Only 6 - 14 characters)");
        new_UserName = br.readLine();
        if (new_UserName == null)
            break; // User ended the conversation
        if (!new_UserName.matches(userName_Pattern)) {
            System.out.println("Username must contain only letters and numbers and be between 6 and 14 characters in length");
        }
        else
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to introduce a local variable for this, it might decrease performance but most likely today's compilers will optimize them out.

If an expression is of type `boolean`, you don't need to compare it to `true`:

```
boolean b = ...;
if (b)
    System.out.println("b is true");
else
    System.out.println("b is false");
```

Also `String` has an `isEmpty()` method which you should prefer to testing 0 length:

```
String s = "";
if (s.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("String has 0 length.");
```

Comment: I agree, to check emptyness of a String, good practice recommends `isEmpty()` (my SonarQube analyser told me this).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd write this as follows:

```
String askForUsername() {
    for (;;) {
        String userName = ...;
        String validationMessage = validateUserName(userName);
        if (validationMessage == null) {
            return userName;
        } else {
            display(validationMessage);
        }
    }
}

String validateUserName(String userName) {
    if (...) {
        return "Username can not be blank";
    } else if (...) {
        return "Username must be between 6 and 14 characters long";
    } else if (...) {
        return "Username must contain only letters and numbers";
    } 
    return null;
}
```

Alternatively, `validateUserName()` could throw Exceptions. This would be more idiomatic, but require somewhat more code.

Answer (score 0):

I would express it even more briefly:

```
System.out.println("PREFERRED USERNAME (Only 6 - 14 characters)");
String new_UserName = null;
for (new_UserName = br.readLine(); !new_UserName.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,14}"); new_UserName = br.readLine())
    System.out.println("Username must contain only letters and numbers, min 6, max 14");
```